# windows phone 8 Longlistselector , move to specific item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, focus, longlistselector

I have created a longlistselector whose name is **nameLonglist** with using:

```
        public static List<KeyedList<string, WCCWordForList>> sortByAlphaOrder()
        {
            var groupedList =
                    from item in WCCWordCardAndListData.getInstance().wccWordsForList
                    orderby item.word
                    group item by item.word.Substring(0,1) into listByGroup
                    select new KeyedList<string, WCCWordForList>(listByGroup);

            return new List<KeyedList<string, WCCWordForList>>(groupedList);
        }
```

And in the xaml back-code constructor I initialize the itemSource:

```
nameLonglist.itemSource = XXXXX.sortByAlphaOrder();
```

Untill now, my list shows perfectly. But I have another question: I want to move to  one specific item (the 12th item) in this list programmatically. Using **nameLonglist.ScrollTo(nameLonglist.itemSource[11])** doesn't meet my expection. **ScrollTo** just move to the right block of items , not the specific item.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You need to pass the actual databound object you want to scroll into view to the ScrollTo function, not an index.

Comment: sorry, I have modified to the right description. I know how to use ScrollTo , but this just jump to the group header of longlistselector, not the specific item under that group header. Do you know how to do?